# playframework invoke onError method inside Globaj.java object

Tags: java, global, invoke, playframework-2.2, onerror

I am working with global object in Playframework.
I've already created methods:

- onHandlerNotFound (to invoke I have to enter address which is unhandled in routes)
- onBadRequest to invoke I have to enter address with wrong time parameter, like: `Users/edit/t`. Method to edit user expects f.e. integer. It can't handle string

I've created method onError:

```
    public Promise<SimpleResult> onError(RequestHeader request, Throwable t) {
        Logger.error("Request: " + request + "generated error: " + t.toString());
        return Promise.<SimpleResult>pure(internalServerError(
            views.html.errorPage.render("500", "Errors occured")
        ));
    }
```

But I would like to test it. Please tell me how can I invoke this method to test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create entry in routes file:

> GET               /testOnError    controllers.ErrorController.testOnError

Error controller:

```
    public static Result testOnError() {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
```

Navigate to:

```
http://HOST:PORT/testOnError
```